# std::out_of_range when using string find and replace inside while loop

Tags: c++, string, replace, while-loop, find

So I have a task to convert all occurrences of some word in one string to another string. But there is problem with condition of while loop which makes this error

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
>
> what():  basic_string::replace
>
> This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.    Please contact the application's support team for more information. Process returned 3 (0x3)   execution time : 2.751 s

My code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    string str2("three");
    string str("one three two four three three");
    while ( str.find(str2) != NULL ){
    str.replace(str.find(str2),str2.length(),"five");
    cout << str << endl; // i put it inside loop to see output
    }
    cout << str << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

You are checking if `str.find(str2)` had an occurrence comparing it to `NULL`, but this is wrong, because `NULL` is a macro that isn't meant for that and often expands into `0`, which *can* be a valid index. You should compare it to `std::string::npos`. After doing this change, your code will work.

Edit : `std::string::npos` corresponds to `18446744073709551615` when testing on coliru. So that clearly isn't a valid index in your string.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

This condition

```
while ( str.find(str2) != NULL ){
```

does not make sense because a call of `find` can return `std::string::npos` that is not equal to zero. In this case the code has undefined behavior.

You can apply the following approach

```
std::string str2("three");
std::string str("one three two four three three");

const char *five = "five";
size_t n = std::strlen(five);

for (std::string::size_type pos = 0;
    ( pos = str.find(str2, pos) ) != std::string::npos; pos += n)
{
    str.replace(pos, str2.length(), five);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it's caused because `str.find(str2)` returns `-1` if `str2` is not existed in the `str`. You can use a variable `pos` to save the found position, so that you will not need to re-invoke `find` function. The solution is supposed as following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main () {
  string str2("three");
  string str("one three two four three three");
  int pos = str.find(str2);
  while (pos > 0) {
    str.replace(pos, str2.length(), "five");
    pos = str.find(str2);
    cout << str << endl; // i put it inside loop to see output
  }
  cout << str << endl;
  return 0;
}
```